# shutdown.exe timer

Tags: windows, command-line, shutdown, script

I'm trying to run

```
shutdown.exe -l -t 10
```

only showed shutdown help manual.

I thought of inelegant but working solution of

```
ping -n 10  localhost
shutdown.exe -l
```

How wasteful is this solution?

I thought of downloading sleep.exe, but I want my bat file to work on a machine with no previous preparations.

Any more ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If it's showing the help manual, that means there is a problem with your syntax - but I can't figure out what it is. Here are the command-line args: http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm

Comment: It works for me, although it doesn't wait 10 seconds for some reason, it just logs out immediately

Comment: @Michael: It's not supposed to wait. The -t arg is a *timeout* not a wait period.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that the -l command is for some reason not compatible with -t.

if you wanted to shutdown the command shutdown -s -t 10 would work, if you wanted to log off after while, you could try using the at command, which schedules a process to be run at a certain time.

at [time] shutdown -l . Not as nice but should work

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the -l option just logs you off, it doesn't shutdown nor restart the computer. You could try using

> shutdown -l

And it should logoff the computer after 30 seconds.

Anyway, the syntax

> shutdown -l -t 10

Is correct, try to copy that line if it doesn't work.

Comment: No, using the -t with -l still just brings up the help details

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/logout/

> Description
>
> Logout is a simple command line utility to silently force close running applications and log off the current Windows user after a provided number of minutes.
>
> example: "logout 24" would log off the current user after 24 minutes.

Comment: Care to explain a little what this does?